# Developer console causes internal system error

Tags: app-development, developer-console

I've noticed over the last week or so that when I have the *developer console open* and am working on my developer orgs that my `@RemoteAction` methods are returning an internal error from SFDC.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

If I close the developer console, the errors go away, but that doesn't do me much good for debugging my apps.

Thanks

[image: developer console error]

This isn't isolated to a single org either.

Comment: I would contact Salesforce Support; It sounds like a genuine bug in their platform.

Comment: Yeah I don't want the brain-damage...sometimes I find the time genuinely isn't worth it. Bugs seem to resolve themselves after some time goes by... if anyone has any insight I just figured I'd ask...

Comment: Any time you get an internal error like that you can contact Salesforce support and they should be able to look it up by the number you give them and get a log of the error.  When you receive one of these it's typically a bug.  You can also check the known issues list at: http://success.salesforce.com/issues_index

Comment: +1 for reporting the bug. @jordan.baucke - bugs only resolve themselves because someone else reports them and they get fixed (ok, sometimes we find them ourselves!). The sooner you report the bug, the sooner it gets fixed!

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I also hate logging cases with salesforce. But I second what @metadaddy said, It must be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can try is restarting your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a server error, probably related to the logging code. Creating a case would make it possible to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have been seeing with my developer org too for the longest I can remember since the last 2 releases

The best thing to do is close the log it tries to open out of no where and restart dev console again.

I believe it is trying to load some resource and fails when I try to debug.

I can reproduce this any day any time :( and was referring about this error to Peter Wisnovsky

[Developer Console Takes Lot of Time to load](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/developer-console-takes-lot-of-time-to-load/3772#comment4637_3772)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Additionally this is not org based , I have seen this error happen with one of the companies, mostly NA instances seem to have this error. The CS instances are pretty ok with dev console

Comment: I also get this error all the time