# Developer Console Takes Lot of Time to load

Tags: developer-console

Anybody has any idea why developer console of mine taking very long time to load after winter 13 release ?

Comment: What browser do you use ?

Comment: IS it always? or specific queries? actions?

Comment: Always and on chrome mostly

Comment: I tried using dev console and moved away from it after a while, its good for checking heap dumps as of now. I would still recommend using Eclipse or Maven's mate for better overall productivity.

Comment: Thanks for that reply and what i observed is its bulky now nad takes lot of time to load .Sometimes its helpful especially say you have to copy ID and inspect in UI and inspect so new console was helpful

Answer (score 2):

We are always interested in hearing about problems people might be experiencing with the developer console. Can you be more specific about the issue you are having? When are you seeing this?

- Initial load time with empty console (is the JS code not getting cached?)
- Load time for a log (how big is the log?)
- Load time for source code (how big is the file and how many files do you have?)

Thanks, we look forward to understanding your problem better.

Comment: Long ago I used to cry about dev console prolems and gave up.
1) "Invalid session from server" This is the most annoying error the dev console started since the last release. Every time I open the console it throws "Invalid session" and I had to close the raw log open in the log window and close the dev console and reopen again
2) I am not sure if many face this issue . The scroll bar seems to get buggy and the logs that recorded do not seem to be readable. 
Dev console is an awesome tool to me only if I do not know what workflows/triggers are getting fired. I am stuck with monitoring :(

Comment: Sorry to hear it. We've taken steps to improve logging on our side to diagnose problems hit by users and to better tune performance. If you are still being blocked by some issues we are anxious to get to the bottom of it.